# A child with `overflow-y: auto` in a grid container is not scrollable

Tags: css, tailwind-css

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="h-screen grid grid-rows-[auto,1fr]">
  <div class="bg-slate-300 h-24 flex items-center px-4">
    <h1 class="text-3xl">Navbar</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="p-4 gap-2 grid grid-rows-[auto,1fr]">
    <h1 class="text-3xl">Title</h1>
    <div class="gap-4 grid grid-rows-[auto,1fr]">
      <div class="flex">
        <button class="btn border rounded p-2">Button</button>
      </div>
      <div class="overflow-y-auto flex flex-col gap-2">
        <div class="h-[200px] bg-slate-100"></div>
        <div class="h-[200px] bg-slate-100"></div>
        <div class="h-[200px] bg-slate-100"></div>
        <div class="h-[200px] bg-slate-100"></div>
        <div class="h-[200px] bg-slate-100"></div>
        <div class="h-[200px] bg-slate-100"></div>
        <div class="h-[200px] bg-slate-100"></div>
        <div class="h-[200px] bg-slate-100"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the `div` with class `overflow-y-auto` to be scrollable, but it doesn't work as expected. Specifing a height to the `div` will make it scrollable, but I want the `div` to occupy the rest space of it's parent.

Comment: is this style you want:  "<div class="flex flex-col gap-2 overflow-y-auto" style="display:block;height:200px">"

Comment: @waiaan I want the scroll container to occupy the rest space of it's parent, so I use the `grid-rows-[auto,1fr]` on the parent div. I don't want to give a height to the scroll container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid children don't get "shrink" by default.
You'll need to explicty use `minmax(0,1fr)`. It gets tricky when you have so many nested grids. (Consider using only where its necessary)
After that, you need to say to your flex children, to not shrink as well, so they can overflow and scroll.

You may need to run and view it by clicking in the "full page" button.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="h-screen grid grid-rows-[auto,minmax(0,1fr)]">
  <div class="bg-slate-300 h-24 flex items-center px-4">
    <h1 class="text-3xl">Navbar</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="p-4 gap-2 grid grid-rows-[auto,minmax(0,1fr)]">
    <h1 class="text-3xl">Title</h1>
    <div class="gap-4 grid grid-rows-[auto,1fr]">
      <div class="flex">
        <button class="btn border rounded p-2">Button</button>
      </div>
      <div class="overflow-y-auto flex flex-col gap-2">
        <div class="shrink-0 h-[200px] bg-slate-100"></div>
        <div class="shrink-0 h-[200px] bg-slate-100"></div>
        <div class="shrink-0 h-[200px] bg-slate-100"></div>
        <div class="shrink-0 h-[200px] bg-slate-100"></div>
        <div class="shrink-0 h-[200px] bg-slate-100"></div>
        <div class="shrink-0 h-[200px] bg-slate-100"></div>
        <div class="shrink-0 h-[200px] bg-slate-100"></div>
        <div class="shrink-0 h-[200px] bg-slate-100"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```